# How to call destroy() method in Chart.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, chart.js

When I switch between tabs I need to draw a new chart, but before that I need to call destroy() method , otherwise it shows data from previous chart. `this.displayChart().destroy()` does not work. Here check my sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-currying-eqr43

```
  displayChart = () => {
    const { budgetData, currentIndex } = this.state
    let colors = []
    Object.keys(budgetData[currentIndex].expenses).map(d => colors.push(this.getRandomColor()))
    const chart = document.getElementById('Chart');

    return new Chart(chart, {
      type: 'pie',
      options: {
        // maintainAspectRatio: false,
        hover: false
      },
      data: {
        labels: Object.keys(budgetData[currentIndex].expenses),
        datasets: [{
          data: Object.values(budgetData[currentIndex].expenses),
          backgroundColor: colors,
        }]
      }
    });

  }
```

calling displayChart func:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (prevState.currentIndex !== this.state.currentIndex) {

      //this.displayChart().destroy() <= here is the problem
      this.displayChart()
    }
  }
```

Comment: I didn't get the problem. I tried the sandbox but I'm not sure if the problem that you said was the one where when it hovers on a specific part of the chart, the first graph is being rendered.

Comment: @suguspnk You need to switch tab, and hover on chart. It gonna display previous chart data. I need to somehow destroy prev chart

Comment: Anyway, after some investigation, I think the problem lies here: this.setState({ budgetData: response.data }, () => this.displayChart()). There's a chart instance after the callback and you don't have any reference to it so it's like a memory leak if my understanding is correct. Feel free to correct me if I'm wrong. :)

Comment: Yes, I think the problem that I saw is the one that you indicated.